# cygwin root point to previous user

Tags: git, command, cygwin

I was trying to use $ cd ~/.ssh to generate ssh key for github, but shows me -bash: cd: /cygdrive/c/Users/xxxxxx/.ssh: No such file or directory. I reinstalled this on this machine, is there a way to change xxxxxxx to my folder? Change the root of cygwin? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to do this:

```
SET HOME=%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%
```

Either make it a [permanent part of your user environment](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726962.aspx) or add it to `c:\cygwin\cygwin.bat` (and use that every time you start bash).

Comment: Thank you very much, I was so stupid did see the previews user actually set the home path in system variables manually.